# Django_like traceback

Tags: python, django

I am using django like..to search model in Django application it was working fine ..but when I tried to deploy it on remote machine it is error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "./couponRestApi/urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 25, in autodiscover
    mod = import_module(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_like/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    QUERY_TERMS['like'] = None
```

So try to install django_like but it is already installed...

```
sudo pip install django_like
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-like in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

Can some one please help me? Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Try doing what `pip` asks you to do: `sudo pip install django_like --upgrade` :) `django_like` already installed, but it might be an outdated version that does not play well with the rest of your code.

Comment: nothing same ...message that i have updated version....

Comment: is that the entire stacktrace ?

Comment: @karthikr is politely implying that you *haven't* included your entire stack trace. There should be another few lines at the bottom that explicitly define *what* exception has been raised. Without that we're  just guessing.

Comment: the problem is not with the installaiton. May be it is some setting you are forgetting to update

Comment: Yes i am sorry i forgot this `TypeError: 'set' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: I think it has something to do with python path of my app see this error `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)`

Comment: I would also suggest you use virtualenv. You won't need to do sudo with pip, and you can pip freeze your local env to make sure the live environment has the same versions as your local.